# ListView QueryString Security

Tags: asp.net

I've a ListView with HyperLink where I pass the orderID. I'm worried that query string is security risk given that end user can modify it.

Could you please suggest any other options I can take? It's a ListView and looks like i dont have much options..

This is what I'm doing at the moment at ListView:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
   NavigateUrl='<%#"~/OrderDetail.aspx?ordid=" + 
   Eval("OrderId")%>'><%# Eval("OrderID") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Session variable to store the value and then use that in place of a QueryString.

Secondly if you use a QueryStringthen it would be better to encrypt it. Take a look here to see how it can be done: [Query string encryption for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Akhtar, is there anyway I can encrypt the OrderId before they get loaded to ListView? At this stage I'm doing something like this:
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%#"~/OrderDetail.aspx?empid=" + Eval("OrderId")%>'><%# Eval("OrderID") %></asp:HyperLink>

Comment: You need to pass the encrypted value in query sting, you can use RowDateBound event something like, where you can set NavigateURL property of hyperlink and then assign there an encrypted value to query string.

Comment: can't find rowDataBound event, is this for ListView or sqldatasource

Comment: use ItemDataBound event instead.

Comment: hmm...sorry but how do I get the orderId to be encrypted from with in that ItemdataBound event. Also the specific naigatURL controls as there are many on the ListView when it gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using cryptography here ...

Refer to [Query string encryption for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/QueryStringEncryptionNET.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Akhtar, is there anyway I can encrypt the OrderId before they get loaded to ListView? At this stage I'm doing something like this:
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%#"~/OrderDetail.aspx?empid=" + Eval("OrderId")%>'><%# Eval("OrderID") %></asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could decode/decrypt the info that you pass using query string but usually you can add some checks in the target page before you use the information from the query string to prevent bad things from happening. Checks like, is the info valid; does the user have privilege to access this info, etc.